# Eventfilter didn't receive any TouchEnd event in Qt5.9.2 QML application on embedded Linux of imx6

Tags: qml, touch, qt5, imx6

There is a imx6 board with linux3.0.35&Qt4.8.5.
I have updated Qt4.8.5 to Qt5.9.2 by cross compile Qt5.9.2 source code.
QML application can build OK and display OK with Qt5.9.2.
But touch invalid, although the touch display work well.

The log in eventfilter() as below:

```
QEvent::Type(ChildAdded)
QEvent::Type(TouchBegin)
QEvent::Type(TouchBegin)
QEvent::Type(TouchBegin)
QEvent::Type(TouchBegin)
QEvent::Type(Timer)
QEvent::Type(UpdateRequest)
QEvent::Type(TouchUpdate)
QEvent::Type(ChildAdded)
QEvent::Type(TouchUpdate)
QEvent::Type(ChildAdded)
QEvent::Type(TouchUpdate)
QEvent::Type(ChildAdded)
QEvent::Type(TouchUpdate)
```

Why there are four TouchBegin in the log, although with one touch?
Why there isn't any TouchEnd in the log?

PS:
My cross compile configure as below:

> ./configure -release -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -no-opengl -opengl es2 -prefix ~/qt5.9.2-arm -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools  -nomake tests  -skip qtandroidextras  -skip qtconnectivity  -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad  -skip qtlocation -skip qtmacextras  -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtpurchasing -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialbus -skip qtspeech -skip qtsvg -skip qttools -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwebview -skip qtwinextras  -no-feature-iconv -no-feature-gestures -no-qml-debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set QT_QPA_GENERIC_PLUGINS as tslib and evdevkeyboard, but not evdev.
The issue was fixed.

```
export QT_QPA_GENERIC_PLUGINS=tslib:/dev/input/ts0,evdevkeyboard:/dev/input/event6
```